# Create an double array in TypeScript and fill it

Tags: javascript

I want to export a ngx-datatable, I have already look on the web if it was possible, but apparently, with ngx-datatable, it is not possible to do it with a simple function. So I try to create my own cliclable button, to extract the data of my array.

The array on my website is like this:

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/45/3/1573045388-stackover.png

I want to export this array in a xlsx file, with the same "look".

So to fill my double array with the value stock in my website ( This is not my code, I am just a intern in my startup so it's complicated to explain. ) The value are stock in row, to have the first name of the person for example, I have to use row.first_name like in the exemple below.

```
this.rows.forEach(element => {
  TableData.push([element.first_name + ' ' + element.last_name], [element.status], [element.address_from_locality], [element.address_to_locality]);
  i++;
});
```

I try this way too

```
var TableData = [];
      this.rows.forEach(element => {
        TableData.push(element.first_name + ' ' + element.last_name);
        TableData.push(element.status);
        TableData.push(element.address_from_locality);
        TableData.push(element.address_to_locality);
      });
```

But these way are not functional, they only give me a simple array, but I need this way :

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/45/3/1573045738-stockarray.png

In the end, I want to export this double array with in a xlsx file, with xlsx, and I use this code:

```
const wb = xlsx.utils.book_new(), ws = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(TableData);
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws);
    xlsx.writeFile(wb, filename);
```

Can you help me to find the solution ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: From all that you have written- I still have no idea how your source data looks and what you're trying to construct with it. Its very good you show us what you tried, but we still need more info about what you're trying to do. Please make your post more clear :)

Comment: Oh sorry, it was clear in my mind, I will modify my post ! :)

Comment: so you want array of arrays, that each inner array represnts a row in the example xlsx file? It's really best if you just show in JS structures what do you expect... like 
"I get array of objects that look like `[{firstname: 'a', lastname: 'b', to: 'destination', from: 'source'}, {firstname: 'a2', lastname: 'b2', to:'destination2', from: 'source2'}]` and I expect to get array like this: `[ ['a', 'b', 'destination', 'source'], ['a2', 'b2', 'destination2', 'source2'] ];`

Comment: just give us the data structures that you want to trasform from and into. its not helping if I see it on the website, I still dont know *how* it is stores in your code

Comment: In the xlsx file for example, the A1 is the first name of the first row, B1 the status of the first row, A2 the first name of the second row, B2 the status of the second row, like the example I give with the excel screen

Comment: So you trying to transform array of objects into array of arrays? where each object turns into an array containing only the values, without the property names. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes it's that ( Sorry i'm intern and I've just started the Angular/Javascript )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've done.

This is the code if you need:

```
ExportToExcel() {
    var filename = 'TalentTable' + '.xlsx';
    var i = 0;
    var TableData: string[][];

    TableData = [];

    this.rows.forEach(element => {
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        TableData[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
          TableData[i][j] = null;
        }
      }
    });
    this.rows.forEach(element => {
      TableData[i][0] = (element.first_name + ' ' + element.last_name);
      TableData[i][1] = element.status;
      TableData[i][2] = element.address_from_locality;
      TableData[i][3] = element.address_to_locality;
      i++;
    });
    var wscols = [
      { wpx: 150 },
      { wch: 30 },
    ];
    const wb = xlsx.utils.book_new(), ws = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(TableData);
    ws['!cols'] = wscols;
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws);
    xlsx.writeFile(wb, filename);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this on the front

```
<ngx-datatable #myTable class="material" [columnMode]="'force'" [rows]="rows" [rowHeight]="'auto'"
      [headerHeight]="'auto'" [footerHeight]="'auto'" [externalPaging]="true" [count]="paginationInfo.totalElements"
      [offset]="paginationInfo.currentPage" [limit]="paginationInfo.pageSize" [scrollbarH]="true"
      [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator" (sort)="onSort($event)" (page)="setTablePage($event)" id="exportable">
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Name" [sortable]="true" [width]="200" [prop]="'first_name'" frozenLeft="true">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          <a [routerLink]="['/',auth.userRID,'talent',row.user_id]">
            {{row?.first_name}}
            {{row?.last_name}}
          </a>
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Status" [prop]="'status'" [width]="200">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          <span class="label" labelState [setType]="'talent'" [labelStatus]="row.status">
            {{ row?.status.replace("_"," ") }}
          </span>
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="From" [sortable]="true" [prop]="'address_from_locality'" [width]="200">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.address_from_locality }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="To" [sortable]="true" [prop]="'address_to_locality'" [width]="200">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.address_to_locality }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Actions" [sortable]="false" [width]="200">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          <div class="btn-group" dropdown container="body">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs dropdown-toggle" dropdownToggle type="button">
              More <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul id="dropdown-basic" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
              <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/call',row.user_id]">Chat</a></li>
              <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/',auth.userRID,'talent',row.user_id]">View
                  profile</a></li>
              <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item"
                    [routerLink]="['/',auth.userRID, 'talent','tasks',row.user_id]">View Tasks</a></li>
              <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item"
                  [routerLink]="['/',auth.userRID,'talent','edit',row.user_id]">Edit profile</a></li>
              <li role="menuitem" dropdown triggers="mouseover"><a dropdownToggle
                  class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">Change
                  status to<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li role="menuitem" *ngFor="let status of statuses|keyvalue">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="switchStatus(row.user_id,status.value)">{{status.key}}</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <!--<ngx-datatable-column name="Start Date" [sortable]="true" [prop]="'move_date'">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.move_date | date }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="End Date" [sortable]="true" [prop]="'end_date'">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.end_date | date }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Email" [sortable]="true" [prop]="'user_email'">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.email }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Onboard Date" [sortable]="true" [prop]="'created_at'">
        <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
          {{ row?.created_at | date }}
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>-->
    </ngx-datatable>
```

And I want to export all these row value in a xlsx file

Comment: thats is wayyyy to much code for me to read lmao. all I needed was for you to `console.log(element)` so I can see what it looks like. I got you now, building you a solution in a sec

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this should work for you:

```
let resultArray = this.rows.map( {first_name, last_name, status, address_from_locality, address_to_locality} => 
([first_name, last_name, status, address_from_locality, address_to_locality]) );
```

if you need the first inner array to contain the actual filed names (i mean looke like `["first_name", "last_name", "status", "address_from", "address_to"]` ), add this line right after:

`resultArray.unshift(Object.keys(this.rows[0]));` --> this will add the keys of the `element` object to the first place in the array.

EDIT:
also, because you're a beginner, I added here some resources for you to better understand what I did:

[array and object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Array.map() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.unshift() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

[Object.keys() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I don't need a loop to fill the array ?
I do the console.log(element) like you ask, and this is what I have this : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/45/3/1573047536-consolelog.png

Comment: nope, `array.map()` does it for you- it creates a new araray where each element is a result of a certain function (that you provide) executed on the corresponding elemnt of the original array.
it basically does: `newArray[x] = you_func(oldArray[x])`.
Read the sources I added for you to read more :)

Comment: and feel free to comment here if there are more questions, or if my solutions wasn't what you expected :)
if it worked, dont forget to tick the green V and upvote, Thank you :D

Comment: Thank you a lot Gibor, have a nice day

Comment: np :) Please accept the answer if it helpes you, so other users can see this question as done as well

Comment: Ok sorry I was in meeting. The code you give doesn't work, all variable are underline in red and it say :

"Argument of type '{ first_name: any; last_name: any; status: string; address_from_locality: any; address_to_locality: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: IProfile, index: number, array: IProfile[]) => unknown'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'first_name' does not exist in type '(value: IProfile, index: number, array: IProfile[]) => unknown'.ts(2345)"

Comment: ok nvm, the problem is elsewhere: look at the screenshot you gave me of the `console.log(element)`- which is of type IProfile: there is no first_name or last_name in there... you can get properties you do not have. did you expect to get them from elsewhere? There is also no "status" property... ofc that will not work lol

Comment: I'm so stupid .. my bad! It's not working :/ same problem

Comment: the properties you're looking for are not found in `element`... there is no `element.first_name`, this does not exist. that is your problem.